# Restrict Point-to-Site Azure VPN Access for Specific Users to Specific Resources

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

Is there a way to restrict access to Azure resources for certain point-to-site users?  For example, I want to allow a P2S VPN user to have access one VM but not another, or one subnet but not others.  Right now it seems like once you are in, you are in for everything that that VNET can access.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vWAN, You can use P2S user groups + Azure Firewall to achieve this. By using P2S user groups you can make Azure P2S to assign IP's from a specific IP address pool to a group of users. You can then add Firewall rule to allow only this address to access the resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/user-groups-about

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of the dynamic assignment of VPN p2s users, we can't control it via NSG since the client IP changes.
however, with user groups and IP address pools in vWAN, you can set pools as per users. then you control the traffic based on the source IP via NSG or Firewall rules.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/user-groups-create

Otherwise, you control the traffic on source machine i.e, firewall.

Answer (score -2):

To restrict some clients to access to Azure resources like VM or subnet, you could add inbound port rules in the [Network security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) associated with the subnet or NIC of VM. The `Source` in the Security rules would be the internal  IP on the VPN client machine that connects to Azure resources with a point-to-site connection.

For more information, you could refer to the [Azure network security overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/network-overview).

Comment: Thanks Nancy -- but the IP assigned to a client when connecting P2S isn't static.  When you disconnect and reconnect, you might get allocated a different IP.  Unless I am missing something?

Comment: I forgot that the P2S client IP address is not static. You may upvote this similar [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/13073538-possibility-of-restrict-point-to-site-vpn-access-t). Currently, in this scenario, you could not restrict the VPN client to a specific resource unless the client is disconnected or revoke a client certificate to forbid it. If you mean some users to access the VM, the VM and users, should in an AD domain environment, then you can restrict users with a domain security policy that restricts some users to access domain VMS.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this with a VPN Appliance like OpenVPN.net by defining User Groups and applying IP restriction per group.
Look into "Access Control" section at
https://openvpn.net/access-server-manual/user-management-group-permissions/

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Also, this isn't the place to recommend products or services.